# SkinClass for TextInput which can dispatch keyDown & display softKeyBoardType correctly

Tags: apache-flex, textinput

Encountering this issue on Flex spark TextInput (for mobile):

1) TextInputSkin can dispatch keyDown but can't correctly display softKeyBoardType set like "number".
2) StageTextInputSkin can display softKeyBoardType correctly but can't dispatch keyDown.

From all my searches, it seems that these are limitations of such skins.

I needed to have keyDown in order not to get the keyed-in character  for some validation and have it not displayed in the textInput by cancelling the event.

My other option is to look for other way to get the character being keyed-in before without it being displayed in the textinput and still using the StageTextInputSkin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When the user interacts with the default soft keyboard for the TextInput and TextArea controls, the keyUp and keyDown events are dispatched only for a small subset of keys. To capture individual keypresses for all keys, use the change event. The change event is dispatched whenever the content of the text input control changes. The disadvantage of this is that you do not have access to properties of the key that was pressed and you must write your own keypress logic.
When the user interacts with the soft keyboard for TextField-based controls, events such as keyUp and keyDown work for all keys. The following example uses the keyUp handler to get the current key and apply a style to the Label control based on the key code. Because the requestSoftKeyboard() method raises the keyboard for the Label control and not the TextInput or TextArea controls, the application uses the TextField-based keyboard.
For more information,please check for this site:http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS82181550ec4a666a39bafe0312d9a274c00-8000.html#WS19f279b149e7481c-66e67e6c13313699023-8000

Comment: Thanks! I have already read about it. What I needed is to be able to use the keyDown event in the textinput so that I could get the character input and cancel the event so that it will not be displayed in the textinput. I needed it the character to be validated first. And also the textinput should display correctly the softKeyBoardType which is in this case for "numbers".